# Equivalent Conditions for a matrix to have full rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $n \times p$ matrix with $n>p$. I'm wondering the following statement is true.

(i) $A$ has full rank 
(ii) $Ax=0$ if and only if $x=0$ 
(iii) $Ay \neq 0$ for any $y \neq 0$

I know (i) and (ii) are equivalent, but not sure if (i) and (iii) are equivalent or not...

Comment: Here's a hint: What's the difference between (ii) and (iii)?

Comment: Since $A$ is not full rank if there is $y \neq 0$ that leads to $Ay=0$, (i) and (iii) seem to be equivalent. Am I correct or missing something?

Comment: That $A0=0$ is always true. So the real content of (ii) is the implication "if $Ax=0$, then $x=0$". You can likewise rephrase (iii) as "if $y\neq 0$, then $Ay\neq 0$". Now note, written this way, they are plainly equivalent: (iii) is the contrapositive of (ii). So (ii) is equivalent to (iii). Since (i) is equivalent to (ii), that means (i) is also equivalent to (iii).

Comment: Manty thanks for your comment!

Comment: For $n > p$, the matrix is full rank if the matrix is full column rank (i.e. $\text{rank}(A)=\min(n,p))$. By applying the linearly independent vectors definition, we get 
$$
x_1 A_1 + x_2 A_2 + \cdots + x_p A_p = 0
$$ 
where $A_*$ denotes the $\text{k}^{th}$ column of $A$. Therefore, $Ax=0$ if and only if $x=0$ and (i) is equivalent to (ii) & (iii).

Answer (score 1):

Since $A(0)=0,$ (ii) is equivalent to
$$Ax=0\implies x=0.$$

Without any further knowledge in linear algebra, you should be certain that (ii) and (iii) are equivalent, because $P\implies Q$ and $\neg Q\implies\neg P$ are equivalent.